# nodejs add new field in json object that does not exist

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to return a json with new field other then the fields that are already in it.
The json is structured like this:

```
objJson={
 istructor_id:"12345",
 student_id:"333",
 date: "2022-10-5"
}
```

I want to add 2 new fields:

```
istructor_name:"john"
istructor_surname:"west"
```

I tried somethin like this:

```
objJson['istructor_name']= "john";
objJson['istructor_surname']= "west";
```

and when I code:
console.log(objJson.istructor_name)
//output: john
It seems to work, but if I try:

console.log(objJson);
//output:

```
{
 istructor_id:"12345",
 student_id:"333",
 date: "2022-10-5"
}
```

EDIT: The JSON on which I am working is returned by the objJson=await model.find().exec()

all code:

```
function posizione_dati_istruttore(istructos_id,istructors_data){
    for(let i=0;i<istructors_data.length;i++){
        if(istructors_data[i]._id.toString()===istructor_id)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

router.get('/mieGuide',async(req,res)=>{
    var student_id=req.query.my_id;
    var drivings=await Prenotations.find({student_id:student_id},{student_id:0}).exec();

    var istructors_ids=[];
    for(let i=0;i<drivings.length;i++){
        istructors_ids.push(drivings[i].istructor_id);
    }
    const istructors_data= await Istructors.find({_id: {$in: istructors_ids}},{_id:1,name:1,surname:1}).exec()
    var pos=0
    for (let i=0; i < drivings.length; i++){
        pos=posizione_dati_istruttore(drivings[i].istructor_id,istructors_data);
        if(pos<0){
            console.log("error");
            res.status(400).json({err: "error"});
        }
        
        drivings[i]['istructor_name']= istructors_data[pos].name;
        drivings[i]['istructor_surname']= istructors_data[pos].surname;
        
    }
    console.log(drivings);
    res.status(200).send();
})
```

Comment: actually, it logs `{ "istructor_id": "12345", "student_id": "333", "date": "2022-10-5", "istructor_name": "john", "istructor_surname": "west" }`, I mean your code works as it is

Comment: you can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/285spcuq/

Comment: This should work. Show the whole code so that the real issue could be identified.

Comment: I added the whole code, a part is in my native language, I hope is not a problem

Comment: which is it, `dati_istruttori` or `istructors_data`? I mean, here you wrote `const dati_istruttori= await Istruttore.find( ....` but then you refer to some other variable "istructors_data" here `pos=posizione_dati_istruttore(guide[i].id_istruttore,istructors_data);`

Comment: now it should be right

Comment: `for(let i=0;i<guide.length;i++){` should now be `for(let i=0;i<drivings.length;i++){`

Comment: yes, sorry fot that

Comment: I wonder what do your data structures look like. I tried to replicate your code on jsfiddle, "imaging" what's in drivings and istructors_data. Please have a look at it, maybe you can clarify what's different: https://jsfiddle.net/sac90714/

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing shouldn't cause any problems and gove the output you are expecting anyway,

You an return a new json onbject with the new fields and use spread operator (...) to keep the old fields.

Like

```
return {istructor_name:"john",istructor_surname:"west",...objJson}
```

Comment: I edit my question because in my project it doesnt gave the output expected but if i try with a small part of code like the one that I wrote on my question it works perfectly